# .htaccess behaving differently on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

So I have a website that successfully rewrites the url parameters to a clean url but on another server the same `.htaccess` does not work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
  RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteRule ^project/(\d+)*$ ./project.php?project=$1
</IfModule>
```

What is not working is the last line there. I need `something.com/project/star-trek` to be the url the user gets when clicking a link, but they are served up `something.com/project.php?project=star-trek` while still seeing the clean url.

On Server1 this code above works perfectly but the same code on Server2 does not. RewriteRule does work on Server2 because we can use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This does work to remove the '.php' on Server2 as well as Server1.

I did check that .htaccess is being allowed in the httpd.conf and I have changed all the AllowOverwrite(s) to All

I'm at a loss here and would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it looks as though the `href` in your source code is probably `/project.php?project=star-trek` ... and because `/project.php` **is** a file, it doesn't fulfil both the `-d` **and** `-f` conditions of your `RewriteCond`s?

Comment: No the href is /project/star-trek, but the server needs to serve up project.php?project=star-trek.  Much like most CMSs run everything out of index.php and change it up based on the URL params but show something.com/some/page

Comment: that's what I guessed you wanted just making sure ... `^project/(\d+)*$` isn't `\d` a digit character (e.g. [0-9] with 8859-1)? At least in RegExp and newer versions of Apache; I don't think Apache 1.3 supported full Perl RegExps.

Comment: Oh ... hang on ... where's the `RewriteEngine On` line?

Comment: Its earlier on in the .htaccess. We're using the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
    RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^project/(.*?)/?$ ./project.php?project=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

That works on my machine, in your original script the bits I noticed were:

- the RewriteEngine wasn't switched on (but it may have been in *httpd.conf* or *httpd-vhosts.conf*)
- the RewriteRule was only matching digits and not allowing trailing slashes: `^project/(\d+)*$`

I've made the RewriteRule an ungreedy wildcard match that excludes trailing slashes; works in an .htaccess file under Apache 2.4.

Comment: I'm a dumbass... Thank you CD001! it was the \d. I switched it to \w and all is working as it should.

I'm wondering why it works on my other site, but I'll fix that as well.

Comment: another note... I did the fix CD001 pointed out and then got a 'Forbidden' message from apache, this led to me removing the './' from ./project.php?...

Comment: Yeah - I had the `./project.php` throw a wobbly with Firefox at first but it was absolutely fine using Chrome so I left it in - I mean, logically, there's nothing wrong with it, *nix filesystems and that, but I suppose it is technically an URL : you'd have got the "Forbidden" message as it was probably trying to load something like `//mysite.com/var/www/mysite.com/htdocs/` (filesystem path munged into the URL)